# how to find number of calls for each active user since their plan start and categorise them as engaged Vs non engaged in SQL

Tags: sql

An engaged user is the one who books at least one call with us every two weeks. If someone is 10 weeks into their plan.
here are two tables:

payment_table

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| user_id | int |
| amount | int |
| plan_name | varchar |
| plan_start_date | datetine |
| plan_end_date | datetime |
| is_active | boolean |

call_event_table

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | int |
| user_id | int |
| call_status | varchar |
| deadline | datetime |
| call_done_time | datetime |
| booking_time | datetime |
| expert_id | int |
| call_type | varchar |

so I can check if is_active=1 and group by on users to see total number of calls using call_end time but how to check if user booked 1 call in every two weeks. i can check how many calls one took from plan start date to plan date.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result also.

Comment: And also add a tag for the dbms you're using.